# A new form to update a record in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app. In this app, I have multiple HABTM relationships between various models. For example, a task can have many learning objectives as well as many missions associated with it. Right now, I have the edit form in modal dialog that edits the task record and is invoked via the edit_task_path(@task) that updates the record. I would like to create a new form that also does that update action; however, I only want this form to be for updating the associations for the tasks. My main question is: how do I create and call a second form to route to the update action for the same record? I would basically like a update_task_path(@task) that handles the update controller action as well.  I've looked at various stack overflows and none specifically address a new form for the update controller action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're routing to the same place you don't really need to do anything other than have a seperate form partial.  I assume the task would have to be valid at the point you're changing associations, and the associations would be valid (or you don't have anything to validate associated objects) otherwise on failure it would render the main form if that is what you've put in the controller.

```
# main_form
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>

# mission_and_learning_objective_form
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :mission_ids, Mission.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :learning_objective_ids, LearningObjective.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You might consider having a seperate controller just for that though

Routes

```
resources :task_settings, only: [:edit, :update]
```

Controller

```
class TaskSettingsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update(task_setting_params)
      redirect_to @task, notice: "Settings Updated"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def task_setting_params
    params.require(:task).permit(mission_ids: [], learning_objective_ids: [])
  end
end
```

View

```
# task_settings/edit
<%= form_for @task, url: task_setting_path(@task) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :mission_ids, Mission.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :learning_objective_ids, LearningObjective.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

To me having a separate controller is a bit cleaner, especially if you want different behaviour if you're only updating the associations.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add in the url to the form.

Comment: Oh this makes perfect sense! My only question is how to use the edit path to call two call 2 different forms? I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm leaning towards the settings controller, I'm just trying to way both options because I will have to do settings controllers for about 4 other models too.

Comment: You'd have two seperate paths.  `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_task_path(@task) %>` and `<%= link_to "Edit Task Settings", edit_task_setting_path(@task) %>`.  Note you can call them whatever you want, it doesn't have to be settings.  I just couldn't think of a good team to group missions and learning objectives.

Comment: I got a missing required key [:id] when I do the edit_task_setting_path(@task). When I added the route to resources page my routes looked like /task_settings/:id/edit.

Comment: Yes. I added it to the task#index page and got the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107149/discussion-between-j-dexx-and-megan-woodruff).